# If $F$ is MHR (log-concave), can the monopoly reserve price exceed the mean?

Tags: inventory, revenue, pricing

Let $V\sim F$ be some positive valued random variable such that $F$ has a monotone hazard rate (alternatively $F$ is log-concave). Let $p = \operatorname{argmax}q(1-F(q))$. We call $p$ the monopoly reserve price, when $F$ is MHR it's well known that $p$ is unique.

I'm interested the relationship between the monopoly price and the mean, specifically I want to know if $p \le \Bbb E[V]$, or else be given an MHR distribution such that $p > \Bbb E[V]$. The best bounds I've seen in the literature come from Lemma 3.4 of [Giannakopoulos *et al.* (2021)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3434423)<sup>1</sup> which shows that $$\frac{p}{\mu} \le \frac{e}{e-1} = 1.58$$ by loosely using a result of [Barlow *et al.* (1964)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-35/issue-3/Bounds-for-Distributions-with-Monotone-Hazard-Rate-I/10.1214/aoms/1177703281.full)<sup>2</sup>.

For the canonical MHR distributions like exponential, uniform, etc. $p$ is either equal to or less than $\mu$ so I believe if the result fails is should take some sort of construction.

---

<sub>References</sub>

<sub>[1] Giannakopoulos, Y., Poças, D., Zhu, K. (2021). Optimal Pricing For MHR and $\lambda$-Regular Distributions. *ACM Transactions on Economics and Computation.* 9(1).</sub>

<sub>[2] Barlow, R. E., Marshall, A. W. (1964). Bounds for distributions with monotone hazard rate, i. *Ann. Math. Stat.* 35(3):1234-1257.</sub>

Comment: You might have better luck on Mathematics StackExchange.

Comment: Note: as outlined in the paper the upper bound of $e/(e-1)$ can also be constructed from [Chawla *et al.* (2010)](https://doi.org/10.1145/1806689.1806733).